# Run a program when .NET project is opened in Visual Studio

Tags: automation, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to run an external program when a .NET project loaded into VS?

Comment: Write an add-in that listens for the SolutionEvents.ProjectAdded event.

Comment: The challenge with this is that I have some projects that require this and not all of them. Example: some projects require Azure emulator. Perhaps running emulator as a pre-build command.